# Unicode character showing question mark after using nvarchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database table I am inserting unicode character, it's working fine.

I am saving data from using .NET API using a stored procedure, but in few system unicode character are showing up as `???`.

On a few other systems, it's working fine. My table columns are of type `nvarchar`.

Here is my query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Account_Master_Save]
    @AccountId INT = 0,
    @AccountName NVARCHAR(250) = '',
    @GroupID INT = 0,
    @DC VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Tag VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @OpBal DECIMAL(18, 2) = 0,
    @Address VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @OtherName NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @LFNo VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Area VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @City VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @State VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Phone VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Contact VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Mobile1 VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Mobile2 VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @MailID VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @BankName VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @AccNo VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @IFSC VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @GName VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Gmobile1 VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Gmobile2 VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Gaddress VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @GCity VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Gstate VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Limit VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @AccountPhoto VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Gphoto VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @OrganizationId INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts]
           ([AccountId], [AccountName], [GroupID], [DC], [Tag], [OpBal], [OtherName],[Address],
            [LFNo], [Area], [City], [State], [Phone], [Contact], [Mobile1], [Mobile2], [MailID],
            [BankName], [AccNo], [IFSC], [GName], [Gmobile1], [Gmobile2], [Gaddress], [GCity], [Gstate],
            [Limit], [AccountPhoto], [Gphoto], [OrganizationId])
    VALUES (@AccountId, @AccountName, @GroupID, @DC, @Tag, @OpBal, @OtherName, @Address,
            @LFNo, @Area, @City, @State, @Phone, @Contact, @Mobile1, @Mobile2, @MailID,
            @BankName, @AccNo, @IFSC, @GName, @Gmobile1, @Gmobile2, @Gaddress, @GCity, @Gstate,
            @Limit, @AccountPhoto, @Gphoto, @OrganizationId)
END
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You are clearly *not* using `nvarchar` *somewhere*. I smell a poorly "parametrised" query that is actually injecting. Show us your *actual* code that is performing the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.

Comment: please check I edited my question,help me.

Comment: That statement is incomplete. Where are the definitions and values of `@AccountId`, `@AccountName`, and `@OtherName` coming from? It's also not valid, you have a comma after `[OtherName]` but don't define another column.

Comment: see again,here OtherName is unicode charater

Comment: Side note, the `sp_`is **reserved** by Microsoft for **S**pecial **P**rocdures, and should *not* be used for user objects. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: You *still* aren't showing us the code that results in the `INSERT` here... I am voting to close this as "Required debugging details", as I can't keep asking for the information and not getting it.

Comment: but its working sometime but sometime not

Comment: now see my whole code

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] here. You *still* (after me asking **four** times) have no shown us the code that is performing the `INSERT`, as a procedure is called and you aren't giving us the (I assume) .net code that is doing that. I still suspect you are injecting values here, and thus why this isn't working. If so the fix is simple; don't inject. It's a huge security vulnerability. **Parametrise**.

Comment: You need to debug for what data it is inserting and what it is not. Then you will get it some time. Without details like when it is not inserting or when it is inserting, we cannot help.

Answer (score 3):

Without know much about what you are trying to do and based on the level of control you have expressed you have and the fact that you are moving varchar and possible nvarchar fields into nvarchar fields, the first thing I would do of course is to convert the data to nvarchar before you insert so this means as an example, if the state field in the database is of type NVARCHAR then

```
@State VARCHAR(50)='',
```

should become

```
@State NVARCHAR(50)=N'',
```

Nvarchar helps with globalization of fields because it allows the database to hold non-english characters that cannot be represented in varchar because they require 2 bytes for storage vs the 1 byte for varchar.

If say you have Japanese language data being stuffed into varchar before insertion to an nvarchar field, in effect you truncate the value before it reaches its destination and may explain your issue.